# Correctly configuring rubycritic and reek to ignore InstanceVariableAssumption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reek

I have a `.reek.yml` file in the root of my rails app with the following content:

```
directories:
  "app/controllers":
    InstanceVariableAssumption:
      enabled: false
```

However, when I run the following command, `rubycritic app lib`, it doesn't seem to respect my reek file. Does anybody know how to correctly configure this file and/or get rubycritic to respect it?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was following `reek`'s configuration for version 5 but only had version 4 installed on my system.